# Angular $http POST changes date format

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Following situation:

I have a form with an `input[date]` field. I transform the values by following code:

```
$scope.entity.date = $filter('date')($scope.entity.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

This correctly formats the date to e.g. `2015-10-27`

When I submit the entity using `$http.post` angular seems to recognize this as date and reformats it to `2015-09-30T23:00:00.000Z`. I am in Germany and we have GMT+1. So angular converts the date to GMT.
Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

**Edit:**

HTML-Code:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="date" ng-model="entity.date" />
</form>
```

JS-Code:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.entity.date = $filter('date')($scope.entity.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  // when debugging this is the point where $scope.entity.date is 2015-10-27
  // so it is the format and date I expect

  $http({
    data: $scope.entity,
    method: POST,
    url: '/resource'
  })
    .success(function(data) {
      // do some stuff
    });

  // when looking into network traffic the request was sent with
  // 2015-09-30T23:00:00.000Z as value for $scope.entity.date
};
```

Comment: Show more code or try create simple plunk representing problem. Angular unlikely performs string->date conversion by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the model value on post. Since your input type is a date, it's getting changed back. This is not a good idea, since the actual form element will change values only after you post.

Any time you need to manipulate your object before saving it's a pretty idea to create a copy of the object. That way it'll behave the way you expect.

```
var entity = angular.copy($scope.entity);
```

Then post the local copy and you should be good.

```
 $http({
    data: entity,
    method: POST,
    url: '/resource'
  })
```